# Symfony2 RuntimeException: The autoloader expected class "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver" to be defined

Tags: php, symfony, capistrano, runtime-error, capifony

I've deployed my site to my development server using Capifony and although it has been deployed correctly when I go the the site i.e dev.xyz.co.uk/app_dev.php I get the following error:

> RuntimeException: The autoloader expected class "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver" to be defined in file "/var/www/vhosts/dev.xyz.co.uk/shared/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Any idea what's causing it? It works fine when deploying to production.

Comment: Just guessing: Have you cleared your cache?

Answer (score 1):

You may check the first line of the file "Driver.php" just to read `<?php`.

If you just read `<?` and tried to deploy on differents servers for dev and prod, just check if they have the same value for "short_open_tag" (in php.ini).
If it's "on" on your prod's server and "off" on your dev's server you may have this error.

Answer (score 0):

It can be problem of accelerator (xcache, eaccelerator, apc). Restart PHP it can help.